# Disable Historical Trending

Tags: history-tracking, field-history

I'm going to disable 'Historical Trending' because when i'm going to change field type number to currency , i'm getting an error that can't change that field type because that field is enable on Historical Trending. My question is , once I disable 'Historical Trending' and upload to production using change set, production history data will be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, I would suggest using a second field for this purpose, and doing some data migration afterwards from the old to the new field. Changing custom field types is always difficult when they are referenced in a lot of places, and combined with the data loss possibilities, I recommend taking that route.

Also have a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/30812/10278).